# Create a button that will switch the font color of the text of the cell between black and white, adjacent to the currently pointing cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am creating a google spreadsheet having two columns. Question and Answers. 
Let's consider there are 100 pairs of cells of questions and answers.
All the questions have font color as black and answers have font color as white. 
If the current cell is pointing to one question then I want to create a button which upon clicking will change the font color to black and so the answer will be visible for its adjacent cell.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this without heavy scripting with just conditional formatting and simple checkboxes:

[image: 0]