# Adding button to every row on google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I have a google sheet that is generated from Google Form. What I am trying to do is that I want every row to have a button that trigger a cloud function based on the data on each row. I would like the button to be created from the script.

Right now, I know that button can only be created as a "float button" and not on every row. 
I also know that some people do a workaround by using checkbox. Is there any workaround beside these on this problem?

**UPDATE**

I know how to insert an image with the code below, but I don't know how to have that image automatically be assigned a script so when you click it runs a script.

```
  function insertImageOnSpreadsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  'https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/images/reports.png');
  var binaryData = response.getContent();

  // Insert the image in cell
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
  sheet.insertImage(blob, 8, 8);
  }
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384615 You can use checkboxes with onEdit trigger

Comment: Is this the only workaround? Because I'm actually trying to avoid the use of checkbox.

Comment: You can set [anchor cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#setAnchorCell(Range)), height, width of the image to give the impression that  the button is inside the cell

Comment: Is this something like adding an image inside the cell? and if so, can we assign script to the image through the google script? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Read the whole link I've provided above.